# InputStream is null when reading a file with size more than 1MB from resources folder

Tags: java, java-io

I am trying to read a text file from resources folder and save it into a String variable. However, when loading the file into an InputStream, it returns the InputStream object as null. The problem is that it only throws an error when file is bigger than 1 MB (I suspect like that, actually). I have tried with rather smaller files and it works as expected.

```
private static String getString(String filename) throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = TextParser.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);
    if (inputStream==null) throw new NullPointerException("InputStream is null");
    final StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    Reader in = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    String line;
    try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(in)) {
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            out.append(line);
        }
    }
    return out.toString();
}
```

The InputStream is null, instead of being a valid object.

Comment: The documentation says that `null` is returned when the resource is not found. Have you checked the jar to verify that the resource actually exists in it?

Comment: i run your method in my computer and read a file which size 13MB,it run good,chenck your file exist or not(the file must in your classpath or classloader can't find it and return null)

Comment: I checked, you're both correct, it was not present. However, why would something like that happen?

Comment: I get caught out with getResourceAsStream(...) when I don't put a leading slash before the resource, for example "/myresource.txt" instead of just "myresource.txt"

Comment: It worked! Just to correct you a little bit, @BretC, "./myresource.txt" worked correctly. Thank you all so much :)

Comment: By the way, do you realise you're removing newline characters from the stream when you convert it into a string like that?

Comment: @DodgyCodeException, only the words inside of the file is important for me, so I think it won't be a problem. Will that make a problem?

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem if you don't care about the newlines. Just make sure the words don't end up getting joined up without any spacing to separate them.